# What is the equivalent of the SQLite datetime function in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sqlite, postgresql

The question is pretty self-explanatory. I'm looking for a PostgreSQL equivalent to the [SQLite datetime function](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DateAndTimeFunctions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, thanks for the answers, they helped point me in the right direction. What I actually was looking for was [to_timestamp](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html).

Answer (score 6):

```
postgres=# select to_char(now(),'YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:ss');
       to_char
---------------------
 2008-09-24 02:09:20
(1 row)

postgres=# select to_char(now(),'YYYY-mm-dd HH24:MM:ss');
       to_char
---------------------
 2008-09-24 14:09:20
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what your're searching for:

timestamp [ (p) ] [ without time zone ] 
or 
timestamp [ (p) ] with time zone

otherwise have a look @ 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/datatype-datetime.html